# Minimum value of integer lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am tryin to retrieve the minimum value of integer in lisp. I found

```
most-negative-fixnum
```

variable that should represent the lowest possible number. whatever i try doing with it is throws error

> Variable `MOST-NEGATIVE-FIXNUM' is unbound.

Is there any specific way how to get the value of variables in lisp? My research about this is without results.

Thanks

Comment: Just tried entering [`most-negative-fixnum`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/convar_most-p_ative-fixnum.html) in SBCL's REPL, and it worked as expected. Which Lisp implementation are you using?

Comment: i am using common lisp if this is what you are asking

Comment: @trolkura: Common Lisp is a language. But which implementation.You might want to show exactly what you are doing. Edit your question to show what input leads to what result.

Comment: @trolkura If `most-negative-fixnum` (or, to be careful, `cl:most-negative-fixnum`) is an error then it's rather unlikely that you are using Common Lisp.

Answer (score 6):

It should work as follows, using for example [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) as an implementation of Common Lisp:

```
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"SBCL"
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-version)
"1.3.12.51-868cff4"
CL-USER> most-negative-fixnum
-4611686018427387904
```

> [...] variable that should represent the lowest possible number

That would be the lowest possible [`fixnum`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_fixnum.htm). You have big numbers too:

```
CL-USER> (* 10000 most-negative-fixnum)
-46116860184273879040000
```

Comment: Now what's interesting is why is that -2^62. What happened to the 63rd bit?

Comment: @BartvanNierop 64 bits minus 1 bit for sign and 1 bit for tagging the value as "immediate".

Comment: I was aware of the sign bit, what does "immediate" mean?

Comment: @BartvanNierop It just means that the remaining bits directly encode the integer value and not a reference in memory to the actual object.

Comment: @BartvanNierop More precisely: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/sbcl-doc/html/sbcl-internals/Type-tags.html

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Since Common Lisp has [bignum](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_bignum.htm) as a part of its specifications there are no limit to how low numeric value you can have from the language point of view.

Since machines have finite memory you will experience that there is a limit to how low the numbers your machine can have. It's not possible for an implementation to know this number or show it to you without actually trying to make it or perhaps the implementation has some ideas of th eoverhead. Without overhead you can use your available memory in bytes as an estimate and you'll have 8 bits per available byte. Eg my machine has about 11GB available so I guess I can use 10GB as the actual storage and sign, ie. 80G bits for the actual number. -2^80G+1 or ~-10^2900000000. You won't be able to print it since you have no available memory.